# Timeout - Clone and Base table

Tags: db2, db2-zos

Procedure of my mainframe job has a step which performs an exchange between clone and base table. This step fails every time the job runs with resource unavailable error. The resource is a package for another program which reads the base table used in my job.

Since the job is failing with timeout error, I usually restart this. But to fix this permanently, is it possible to increase the timeout limit for this EXCHANGE process. In IBM manual, I could see "SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT 30" for this. But is this valid. My EXCHANGE statement between clone and base table is coded in a control card. Is there any possibility I can increase the timeout so that the job does not go into error.

If any further details is required, please let me know

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: ...why is a resource for a completely unrelated program causing your job to fail?  That, I think, is the real thing you want to resolve.  Is the resource actually used by your program?  Is the table switch causing the other resource to be recompiled or relinked (problematic)?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No, the exchange between the tables is not compiling the program (LMCPIT), whose package is flagged as resource unavailable. Is it possible that, since the program LMCPIT is doing select queries on the base table (LMGRPIT01), the exchange step could be waiting for the lock placed on LMGRPIT01 to get released. But then that throw an error reporting the base table as resource unavailable right?

Comment: I'm not that into the weeds, but yes, I imagine that if the other resource is locking the table for reads that would cause the contention.  From some cursory searching, it appears that you're not supposed to have live statements being executed against either table when doing an `EXCHANGE`, so the proper response would be "get the other job to play nice".  For that matter, depending on what that other job is doing, switching the table out from under it could cause data consistency issues.